# cancel friendship confirmation dialog box

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, social-networking, buddypress

I am working on a BuddyPress theme (social network) / WordPress platform. I need a confirmation dialog box to be displayed for the user before deleting a friend. Regarding my code, when I click the "Cancel" button or "OK" button in the confirm dialog, the result is the deletion of the friend.

I want the code to undo the friend deletion when the "Cancel" button is clicked, and to delete the friend only when the "OK" button is clicked.

```
    function my_custom_js() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // Listen for click events on friendship remove buttons
        $(document).on('click', '.friendship-button.is_friend.remove', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          var button = $(this);
          var url = button.data('bp-nonce');

          // Display a confirmation dialog before removing the friend
          if (confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this friend?")) {
            // If the user confirms, send the AJAX request to remove the friend
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: url,
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(response) {
                // If the request is successful, remove the friend from the DOM
                button.closest('li').remove();
              },
              error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.error(status + ': ' + error);
              }
            });
          } else {
            // If the user cancels, do nothing
            console.log('Friend removal canceled.');
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_custom_js' );
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is not working about the code you have provided and what you want help fixing.

Comment: the code I have provided displays a dialog box that includes "Are you sure you want to remove this friend?" with the (ok) button and (cancel) button, when I press cancel button, it deletes the friend, it should undo the deleting friend

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. Pressing the "Cancel" button will cause the `else` branch of your condition to be executed - the AJAX POST call will not be sent. For a very basic example, see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/4gmu9zy0/). So there must be something else going on here in some other part of the code.